# Is the absolute trace of $\frac{xy}{(x+y^4)^2}$ equal to zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ with $q=2^m$ be the finite field of $q$ elements. Let $x,y \in \mathbb{F}_{q}$. Let   $m$ be  any integer. If $xy(x+y)=1$ and $x+y^4\neq 0$, then experiment data for $m=3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ suggest that the absolute trace function from $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ to $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ of the following element:
$$\frac{xy}{(x+y^4)^2}$$
is equal to zero.

I tried to write the above element as $z+z^2$ with $z\in \mathbb{F}_{q}$, but it seems that it is not easy.

Comment: Over $\Bbb{F}_8$ all the solutions of $xy(x+y)=1$ are gotten by applying the symmetries (permute $x,y,x+y$ any which way you want) to a single solution. Over $\Bbb{F}_{16}$ the rational points of this elliptic curve all have their coordinates in $\Bbb{F}_4$ (see the last example in [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2952583/11619), it's really the same curve after the obvious transformation via homogeneous coordinates). This made me suspect that we might be seeing something explained by the law of small numbers.

Comment: (cont'd) Often facts like this can either be proved relatively simply, or counterexamples can be found in large enough fields via some use of exponential sums. I don't see a way of turning this into an exponential sum where we could use Weil-type bounds, and the OP has checked this for bigger fields anyhow.

Comment: (cont'd) Another curious fact is the lack of symmetry in the rational function. It is possible to turn the problem into a more symmetric statement, making the equivalent claim that the quartic we get by multiplying the two quadratic equation related to this trace condition and its $x\leftrightarrow y$ counterpart, when we can claim that the resulting quartic splits completely over $\Bbb{F}_q$. The added symmetry allows us to reduce the number of variables (replacing the equation with a trace condition), but I don't see a way of proving that version either.